# Auto-Moderation Discord.py Bot Message Error?

Tags: python, discord.py

I’m trying to program an auto-moderation that filters bad words out of the chat and then deletes them!

```
@automod.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def words(ctx):
    client.dispatch(event_name='message_event')
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x7bed9f, description='Der Auto-Mod für `words` wurde erfolgreich aktiviert')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@client.event
async def on_message_event(message):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.delete()
```

When I run the code and enter `+automod words` the embed is sent that the automod was activated but I get this error message:

*TypeError: on_message_event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'*

**My question is now what does this error message mean and how do I fix it?**

Comment: when you're dispatching the message_event event, you need to provide the message

Answer (score 1):

Your `message_event` requires the message argument, therefore you need to provide it when dispatching.

```py
bot.dispatch('message_event', ctx.message)
```

Note:
`bot.dispatch` is part of the private api and not in the [official documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) because it will *probably* be removed from the in the next major version of discord.py (2.0).

Comment: `bot.dispatch` was never in the official docs, I also don't think it's gonna be removed since it's part of the core of the library

Comment: It is probably going to undergo some changes in 2.0, [source](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/7295#issuecomment-888589039)

Comment: @Ceres I have now inserted this into my code and I do not get an error message but the message is still not deleted?

Comment: Maybe the wrong message is being passed into the event, because you're just passing the invoking message here, try adding a forbidden word in the invoking command and that should be deleted

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, but I don’t understand where to insert this?

Comment: Exactly where you're dispatching the event, inside the command

Comment: Now i get this Error Message: *TypeError: on_message_event() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filtered_words'*

Comment: you're passing filtered_words as an argument then

Comment: When i pass filtered_words as an argument i will get this Error Message: *discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: filtered_words is a required argument that is missing.* :/

Comment: where are you defining filtered_words? if you're making it into an argument you need to pass that too when u dispatch the event